# org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving fragment: template or fragment could not be resolved

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a weird issue where some of my html files are not being included when I use replace or include. What would cause this?

header.html

```
 <header id="header" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
       <div th:replace="/blocks/topbar :: topbar"></div>
 </header>
```

topbar.html

```
<div class="top-bar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4">
                <div class="top-number"><p><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i>  +0123 456 70 90</p></div>
           </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
            <div class="social">
                <ul class="social-share">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--/.container-->
</div><!--/.top-bar-->
```

Error:

```
 org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving fragment: "~{'/blocks/topbar' :: topbar}": template or fragment could not be resolved (template: "blocks/header" - line 3, col 10)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no `th:fragment="topbar"` in your `topbar.html`.
An additional `<div>` may solve your problem.

```html
<div th:fragment="topbar">
  <!--fragment div start-->
  <div class="top-bar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4">
          <div class="top-number">
            <p><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i> +0123 456 70 90</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
          <div class="social">
            <ul class="social-share">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.container-->
  </div>
  <!--/.top-bar-->
</div>
<!--fragment div end-->
```

Comment: This solved my problem but why does the other includes without the fragment expression work while some does not?

Comment: That I can not say exactly, cause I can never make it work without expression.

Answer (score 2):

You don't always need a th:fragment, you could have used ".top-bar" instead of "topbar":

```
<div th:replace="/blocks/topbar :: .top-bar"></div>
```

Class selectors are totally valid and you have a ton more selector possibilities in thymeleaf, see here: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#appendix-c-markup-selector-syntax